# Get count column if at least one value exist - SQL

Tags: sql

How to create a separate column for each color if at least one value exists in a group by clause?
Does each color column need a separate select statement with group by clause.
Thanks in advance.

For example

```
    SELECT
    COUNT(ColorID) AS IcdCodecount,
    Colorname
    -- Blue -> if at least one value exists in 1, 10, 12
    -- Red -> if at least one value in 0, 3, 4, 15
    -- White -> if at least one value in  11, 12, 13, 14
    -- Yellow -> if at least one value in 20, 21, 22, 23
    FROM
      TestTable
    WHERE ColorID IN (
                      1, 10, 12, -- blue
                      0, 3, 4, 15, -- Red
                      11, 12, 13, 14, -- White
                      20, 21, 22, 23, -- yellow)
    GROUP BY Colorname
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And what results do you want if there are multiple colors?

Comment: What database are you using?  Try looking into pivot table if your db supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
(case when sum(case when colorId in (1, 10, 12) then 1 else 0 end)  > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as is_blue,
(case when sum(case when colorId in (0, 3, 4, 15) then 1 else 0 end)  > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as is_red,
(case when sum(case when colorId in (11, 12, 13, 14) then 1 else 0 end)  > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as is_white,
(case when sum(case when colorId in (20, 21, 22, 23) then 1 else 0 end)  > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as is_yellow
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon.  it's a SQL db.  Trying to get a separate column for each color if at least one value exists.  Case statement with sum will work.

Comment: @IYO . . . That is what this does.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pivot table. Implementation for Oracle is described here:

https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/